# Apache Nifi not working with multiple notes in zookeeper string

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

Below is the version of the Nifi I am using for clustering,

[Apache Nifi Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJHva.jpg)

Also if you can see in the screenshot, this nifi is in clustered with below entries in configuration file,

```
nifi.properties
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=192.168.0.10:2182

zookeeper.properties
server.1=192.168.0.10:2777:3777;2182

state-management.xml
<property name="Connect String">192.168.0.10:2182</property>
```

Below below is the screenshot of the clustered node,
[Clustered Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUYQl.jpg)

I want to setup cluster of 3 nodes. Suppose below are the 3 nodes,

1. Node 1 = 192.168.0.10
2. Node 2 = 192.168.0.20
3. Node 3 = 192.168.0.30

I am able to setup the cluster by using below zookeeper string in the respective nodes,

1. Node 1 = 192.168.0.10:2181
2. Node 2 = 192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.20:2181
3. Node 3 = 192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.20:2181,192.168.0.30:2181

If Node 1 is up and running and I am turning of any other node than Node 1, then cluster is working without any issue.

But problem with above configuration is, if I am turning off the Node 1 (192.168.0.10), then cluster is failing with the connection loss status. As Node 2 and Node 3 waiting for Node 1 which is down which turns into cluster failure.

So I am trying to setup same zookeeper string for all the node at once and trying to start server one by one.

1. Node 1 = 192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.20:2181,192.168.0.30:2181
2. Node 2 = 192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.20:2181,192.168.0.30:2181
3. Node 3 = 192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.20:2181,192.168.0.30:2181

So now Node 2 and Node 3 is already down (like never started). And I am trying to start Node 1 with zookeeper string "**192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.20:2181,192.168.0.30:2181**".

Node 1 not starting it all. I am getting below errors repeatedly for infinite times,

```
2020-08-06 22:55:21,397 ERROR [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background operation retry gave up
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-08-06 22:55:21,397 ERROR [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background retry gave up
org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:972)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-08-06 22:55:21,399 ERROR [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Background operation retry gave up
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:862)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:990)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:943)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:346)
```

Above are infinite logs and even it will start the Nifi. Once I am trying to access the nifi from the browser then I am getting cluster connection error message. Please see below screenshot for your reference.
[Error Prompt On Nifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eveCb.jpg)

In nifi.properties, zookeeper.properties and state-management.xml file having common entry compared to all other nodes. Like below,

**nifi.properties**

```
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties

# web properties #
nifi.web.https.host=192.168.0.10
nifi.web.https.port=2520

# security properties #
nifi.security.keystore=./ext-lib/ssl/keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=jks
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=CskME7zgbZiR1k/vwlPJcOayK4VPl3+gVIq/ZgD9c
nifi.security.keyPasswd=CskME7zgbiR1k/vwlPJc3OayK4VP3+gVIq/ZgUD9c
nifi.security.truststore=./ext-lib/ssl/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=dHNilK1qAKsX5ee3e7gcbg/yQQsVSbUrxGG4Lhr7Y
nifi.security.needClientAuth=true
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=file-identity-provider
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=true

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=192.168.0.10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=2510
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=1 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=10

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6343
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=4
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=192.168.0.10:2182,192.168.0.20:2182,192.168.0.30:2182
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
```

**zookeeper.properties**

```
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
syncLimit=5
tickTime=2000
dataDir=./ext-lib/zookeeper-home/zookeeper
autopurge.snapRetainCount=30

server.1=192.168.0.10:2777:3777;2182
server.2=192.168.0.20:2777:3777;2182
server.3=192.168.0.30:2777:3777;2182
```

**state-management.xml**

```
<stateManagement>
    <local-provider>
        <id>local-provider</id>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.local.WriteAheadLocalStateProvider</class>
        <property name="Directory">./state/local</property>
        <property name="Always Sync">false</property>
        <property name="Partitions">16</property>
        <property name="Checkpoint Interval">2 mins</property>
    </local-provider>
    
    <cluster-provider>
        <id>zk-provider</id>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider</class>
        <property name="Connect String">192.168.0.10:2182,192.168.0.20:2182,192.168.0.30:2182</property>
        <property name="Root Node">/nifi</property>
        <property name="Session Timeout">10 seconds</property>
        <property name="Access Control">Open</property>
    </cluster-provider>
</stateManagement>
```

**Its quite surprising for me. As If I am starting the server with in cluster with single zookeeper string, I am able to start without any issue. Single node is getting into cluster properly.**

```
nifi.properties
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=192.168.0.10:2182

zookeeper.properties
server.1=192.168.0.10:2777:3777;2182

state-management.xml
<property name="Connect String">192.168.0.10:2182</property>
```

**But When I am moving ahead to add more than one node it is failing.**

```
nifi.properties
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=192.168.0.10:2182,192.168.0.20:2182,192.168.0.30:2182


zookeeper.properties
server.1=192.168.0.10:2777:3777;2182
server.2=192.168.0.20:2777:3777;2182
server.3=192.168.0.30:2777:3777;2182


state-management.xml
<property name="Connect String">192.168.0.10:2182,192.168.0.20:2182,192.168.0.30:2182</property>
```

I am kind of new to the Nifi and working on clustering part. I am able to achieve all the clustering activity by taking reference of available resources and by doing some POC work. But only this is problem where I stuck and not able to move ahead.

I am using SSL Nifi Clustering. Can anyone please help me out with this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend setting up ZooKeeper externally on its own, the embedded ZK provided by NiFi is just for easy testing, but not meant to be used for real.

Comment: @BryanBende Thanks for replying. I have tried with external zookeeper (apache-zookeeper-3.5.8). I am able to start the zookeeper by providing respective entry in configuration file. But when I am starting the nifi instance I am getting connection loss error. I verified all the configuration is correct. I followed this link to do the external zookeeper integration,
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Configuring-an-external-ZooKeeper-to-work-with-Apache-NiFi/ta-p/246791

I am getting repeatedly same connection loss error message which I posted in my question.

Comment: @BryanBende I am able to start Nifi with the external zookeeper. It was my mistake. I did below configuration in the zoo.cfg file to fix the issue,

`clientPort=2182
autopurge.snapRetainCount=30
autopurge.purgeInterval=2
admin.serverPort=2516`

Now I am trying out the usecase which was failing with embedded ZK. Again thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: @BryanBende External ZK worked well. Thanks for help.

Comment: Glad it is working now :)

Comment: Yes @BryanBende. Thanks for your help. As it was almost more than a month I was struggling with Embedded ZK. Its quite strange that  Embedded ZK was not working with same use case. Is there any specific reason for that ? Where do I get the official documentation where it is mentioned that embedded ZK should not use for production ? And why it is not used for real scenario's ?

Also I am having one more question. 
`server.1=192.168.0.10:2777:3777`
What is use of port **2777** and **3777** ? and what other value we can assign here ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is something in the docs, its just something the nifi community has always said. Using embedded ZK creates two problems, 1) if NiFi crashes due to some OOM exception or something else it means you are bringing down one of the ZK instances with it 2) ZK is very sensitive to disk latency so if NiFi is processing a lot of data, you would not want ZK's data to be on the same disks as nifi's repositories

Comment: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_configuration
"There are two port numbers nnnnn. The first followers use to connect to the leader, and the second is for leader election. The leader election port is only necessary if electionAlg is 1, 2, or 3 (default). If electionAlg is 0, then the second port is not necessary. If you want to test multiple servers on a single machine, then different ports can be used for each server."

Comment: @BryanBende I have stuck for one more cluster issue regarding state management. Could you please help me out there. below is the link for the question,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045517/in-3-nodes-of-nifi-cluster-1-node-is-restarted-then-files-are-getting-duplicate