# In 3 nodes of Nifi cluster, 1 node is restarted then files are getting duplicated

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

Suppose I have 3 nodes in cluster,

1. Node A
2. node B
3. Node C

In **state-management.xml** file I am having below configuration,

```
<cluster-provider>
        <id>zk-provider</id>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.zookeeper.ZooKeeperStateProvider</class>
        <property name="Connect String">192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.11:2181,192.168.0.12:2181</property>
        <property name="Root Node">/nifi</property>
        <property name="Session Timeout">10 seconds</property>
        <property name="Access Control">Open</property>
</cluster-provider>
```

I am using external zookeeper with below **zoo.cfg** configuration,

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=./zookeeper
clientPort=2181
autopurge.snapRetainCount=30
autopurge.purgeInterval=2
quorumListenOnAllIPs=true
admin.serverPort=2515

server.1=192.168.0.10:2666:3666
server.1=192.168.0.11:2666:3666
server.1=192.168.0.12:2666:3666
```

All nodes are up and running. If we are processing 10000 files and in middle of the processing if we restart the any node in the cluster then it results in duplicate file processing. And at the end we can see more than 10000 files are processed. In number I can say 12000 files are processed.

Processor configuration which generates the flowfile,

[Processor A Which Generates Flowfile - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzNm1.jpg)

[Processor A Which Generates Flowfile - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG1MS.jpg)

I am suspecting that somewhere state is not getting updated or managed properly. If 1 node processed few files then other node should not process those files. May be I am missing some configuration. can someone please help me to get this sort out.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you show your processors configuration that make flowfile

Comment: Hi @maximeG , Thanks for responding very quick. I have updated my question with 2 screenshot which have processor configuration.